# url rewrite breaks page and doesnt load?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, visual-web-developer

Currently on my website when a user logs it it shows `www.domain.com/userHome.php` and I want it to just show `www.domain.com` so I can have a cleaner url for the user to see.

I had trouble figuring out how to get the url rewrite to just chomp off the end in the address bar. I was following a tutorial [here](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite), and decided to try this in my `.htaccess` file to see if I could get any rewrite working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^userHome.php$ /hello.html
```

when I tried this I was expecting to see www.domain.com/hello.html instead of `www.domain.com/userHome.php` which isn't exactly what i wanted but I am trying to take baby steps as I learn this.

Unfortunetley when I tried this I just got a page not found error when I went to `www.domain.com/userHome.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^hello\.html$  userHome.php [L]
```

Then try to access: www.domain.com/hello.html

Comment: So this code makes hello show up as userHome.php I might be able to work with this. I want it the other way but with nothing after the .com

Comment: Please be more clear about this, what " I want it the other way but with nothing after the .com " means?

Comment: I want the url in the address bar to rewrite to www.domain.com if the user is either at www.domain.com/index.php or www.domain.com/userHome.php

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to use mod rewrite for this. Just use:

```
DirectoryIndex userHome.php index.php index.html index.htm
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I am still trying to figure out whats going on though because I plan on writing some more complicated ones soon that I need to actually know why this simple name change will not work.

Comment: I also want www.domain.com/index.php to be www.domain.com and that code does not fix that too.

Comment: @Mike you mean on the same site? It won't show if you have both, yes. But it should work if you don't have userHome.php present.

Comment: I want the url in the address bar to rewrite to www.domain.com if the user is either at www.domain.com/index.php or www.domain.com/userHome.php